# Chrome crashes with this JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Chrome crashes with this JS.
There is a form with multiply inputs. The JS code has to check before submit were they filled or not. But after success submit Chrome crashes.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var form = $('form#add');
    form.submit(function(){
      var filledInputs = $('form#add input[value!=""]');
      $('form#add input[value=""]').css('border','solid 1px red');
      filledInputs.css('border','');
      if (filledInputs.length >= 9) {
          form.submit();
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What means: "Chrome crashes"?

Comment: `if (filledInputs.length >= 9)` is causing a infinite loop. As is re-submits the form over and over. Just remove the `form.submit();` and it should work.

Comment: why are you submitting again?

Comment: BTW, why setting a variable 'form' if you are still using $('form#add')? Still BTW, should be just: $('#add')

Comment: The question is why does Chrome crash?
So I've got an answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is already submitted, you don't need to submit it again :

```
if (filledInputs.length >= 9) {
    // form.submit();
    return true; // return true is to continue with the form submission
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're function is infinitely recursive when there are `>=9` filled inputs. On submit, the form performs validation, if the validation passes, you make another call to submit, which validates the form, and so on.

If you remove the `form.submit();` and just return `true` the form will submit correctly.

Comment: Thanks. How to check inputs then?

Answer (score 1):

Shortening the code a bit makes the problem obvious:

```
form.submit(function(){
    form.submit();
})
```

This is causing an infinite recursion, which exhausts the stack, and causes usually causes chrome to abort the script (or to crash).

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
form.submit(function () {
    var filledInputs = $('form#add input[value!=""]');
    $('form#add input[value=""]').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
    filledInputs.css('border', '');
    return (filledInputs.length >= 9);
});
```

form will be submitted based on the input fields validation.